# ¿Sacar información de una tabla?

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd

Compañeros, alguien me puede colaborar con este pequeño detalle que tengo necesito sacar la información de una tabla con serenity y java, pero no lo he logrado.

Cuerpo HTML:

```
<table class="table table-datos">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td class="dark-yellow-bg ng-binding">Tasa mes vencida utilizada en la simulación</td>
                            <td class="monto valor ng-binding">1.75%</td>
                        </tr>
```

Java:

```
String tasaMesVencidoTexto = Serenity.getWebdriverManager().getCurrentDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class = 'table table-datos']//tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();
```

Esta es la tabla, en general solo necesito ese dato, si alguien me puede decir donde conseguir información al respecto o decirme de que manera hacerlo, estaría muy agradecido.

Gracias

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @RuslanLópez eh intentado la siguiente manera

'String tasaMesVencidoTexto = Serenity.getWebdriverManager().getCurrentDriver()
                .findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class = 'table table-datos']//tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();'

Cuando lo ejecuto con un debug para revisarlo más a fondo, muestra que no devuelve nada y no eh logrado saber por qué!

Answer (score 0):

Estimado pruebe las siguientes alternativas

1. Verifique su xpath estoy viendo un xpath absoluto, intenta construir un xpath relativo. Te dejo documentación https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html
2. Verifique que no exista un iframe en la estructura del dom, por que si existe un iframe no podras llegar a la tabla y mucho menos capturar lo que tiene.
3. Continua debugendo y probando sus xpath, por que siento que por ahí es el problema el codigo en general lo veo bien.

Saludos.